# Units, determinants and irreducibility.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, normed-spaces, irreducible-polynomials, integral-extensions

Here is the question I want to answer:

Let $B = \mathbb R[x,y]$ where $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ ( the coordinate ring of the unit circle).

Show that $B^* = \mathbb R ^*$.

I know that Since $y$ is integral over $\mathbb R[x]$ there is a ring inclusion $B \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb R[x]),$ called a representation of $B.$ And I found this representation of $B$ because I know that $B = \mathbb R[x] \oplus \mathbb R[x]y$ and multiplication by $y$ is a map of $B$ as an $\mathbb R[x]$-module. And here is this representation $$\phi:B \rightarrow M_{2}(\mathbb R[x]), \phi (a_{1} + a_{2}y) =  \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{2}(1-x^2) \\
a_{2} & a_{1} 
\end{pmatrix} $$

Then I was thinking about using the determinant to solve my questions and I guess I should work in a way similar to $\mathbb Z \sqrt {3}$ but still I am confused about the details.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_1+a_2y$ is a unit, then $\phi(a_1+a_2y)$ must be invertible, so $\det\phi(a_1+a_2y)=a_1^2+a_2^2(x^2-1)$ needs to be a unit of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, i.e., an element of $\mathbb{R}^\times$.  If $a_1a_2\neq 0$, write
\begin{align*}
a_1&=a_{1,m}x^m+a_{1,m-1}x^{m-1}+\dots+a_{1,0}\\
a_2&=a_{2,n}x^n+a_{2,n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_{2,0}
\end{align*}
with $a_{i,j}\in\mathbb{R}$, $a_{1,n}a_{2,m}\neq 0$.  Then $a_1^2+a_2^2(x^2-1)$ has top degree (in $x$) piece
$$
\begin{cases}
a_{1,m}^2x^{2m} & \text{if }m>n+1\\
a_{2,n}^2x^{2n} & \text{if }m<n+1\\
(a_{1,m}^2+a_{2,n}^2)x^{2m} & \text{if }m=n+1
\end{cases}
$$
Can you finish it from here?

Comment: why the first part of your first line should happen ? could you clarify please? I did not see a definition of a unit including invertibility of a matrix before.

Comment: @Confidence Because you know the formula for inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ --- just interchange diagonal, introduce negative sign on the other two, and divide the whole thing by $\det M$.  Either all entries are divisible by $\det M$, or $\det M$ is a unit.  The first case you get $\det M=(\det M)^2\det A$ for some $A$ which also means $\det M\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ is invertible.

Comment: oh I am not getting the idea of the definition of a unit in our context here ... could you clarify it please?

Comment: I do not understand your statement here "Then $a_1^2+a_2^2(x^2-1)$ has top degree (in $x$) piece" could you clarify please?

Comment: If $a_1+a_2y$ is a unit, then there is some $b_1+b_2y$ such that $(a_1+a_2y)(b_1+b_2y)=1$ right?  So we must also have $\phi(a_1+a_2y)\phi(b_1+b_2y)$ is the identity.  (We could so do it via $(a_1+a_2y)(a_1-a_2y)=a_1^2-a_2^2(1-x^2)$ and $B$ is an integral domain).

Comment: yes I agree with that but why do you need to apply  the function $\phi$ to the definition  of  a unit ?

Comment: $a_1^2+a_2^2(x^2-1)\in\mathbb{R}[x]=\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}x\oplus\mathbb{R}x^2\oplus\dots$, so we are just looking at the top degree (in $x$) term of that.